# UITableView "Bind()" methods - any tutorials or examples out there?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have just noticed that UITableView comes with a couple of Bind() methods. Looks like that's an alternative to implementing UITableViewSource over and over again, or am I wrong?
Does anybody have samples? Also any other samples of binding would be interesting, like binding a textfield to a model using MonoTouch.

René

Comment: Uh, what Bind () methods?  There is nothing like that in UITableView.

Comment: I think he is referring to NSObject's Bind method(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking at is:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

This has nothing to do with UITableView or UITableViewSource data binding.

Comment: Aaahhh. Okay. I was mislead coming from Windows Forms etc. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at MonoTouch.MVVM. It is an implementation of MVVM using DataBinding for MonoTouch.Dialog. https://github.com/RobertKozak/MonoTouch.MVVM